# How to programmatically scroll between home screens?

Tags: android, service, accessibility, sensors

I am building an accessibility service just like talkback but instead of touchscreen gestures I'm using mid-air gestures to control the smartphone.

I'm able to navigate through all items of the UI and scroll listViews and ScrollViews using accessibilityNodeInfo successfully. However, when regarding the home screens I don't know how to change between them.

1. How can I do this using AccessibilityNodeInfo? Is it possible? How?
2. If not, can I do this using Intent? I managed to get to the home screen with :`Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
   i.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");`

but I wanted to get a list of home screens and being able to scroll them just as we do with swipe gestures.

3. I have tried to perform simulated gestures without success based on [RemoteDroid](https://github.com/omerjerk/RemoteDroid) by **Omerjerk**.

   ```
   int source = InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN;
   float pressure = 1.0f;

   try {

       ei.injectMotionEvent(source,MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, systemClock.uptimeMillis(), 800,200, pressure );
       ei.injectMotionEvent(source,MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 790, 200, pressure );
       ei.injectMotionEvent(source,MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() , 670,200, pressure );
       ei.injectMotionEvent(source,MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() , 560,200, pressure );
       ei.injectMotionEvent(source,MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() , 450,200, pressure );
       ei.injectMotionEvent(source,MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() , 340,200, pressure );
       ei.injectMotionEvent(source,MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() , 230,200, pressure );
       ei.injectMotionEvent(source,MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 120,200, pressure );

   } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();

   } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();

   }
   ```

Could you help me with any hints on how can I change between screens?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue using AccessibilityNodeInfo to get all nodes of the window even the not visible by the user. Then I focus the element to change the screen